# apt-get is unable to lock the administration directory while installing

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt-get

I'm running Linux Mint 15 with Cinnamon. I'm fairly new to Linux, and I'm operating from an 8 GB memory stick. In the terminal, I typed the following line:

```
sudo apt-get install supertuxkart
```

It was taking hours, so I cancelled using the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>. After that I tried installing `drpython` by doing

```
sudo apt-get install drpython
```

Then it said:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you're new to linux then use the GUI software manager to install things. Why make things harder than they should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`control`+`z` doesn't cancel the command, it pauses it. You need the process to close in order to start a new install. Bring it back to the foreground using the `fg` command, then stop it using `control`+`c`.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue in that case, since the OP was running another `apt-get` process in the background. Forcefully removing the lock and running it a second time could cause problems.